# firefox not display rss feed with interface

Tags: firefox, rss

Firefox displays an interface for RSS instead of the XML of the feed. For example goto: http://www.alistapart.com/site/rss

For some reason this feed is showing the XML in Firefox instead of the interface:
http://www.mmpa.net/feeds/upcoming-events.rss

The xml and Content-Type headers are the same. Anyone see what I am missing? What's the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Firefox doesn't handle the RSS feed correctly if its compressed. (It seems, that is what my tests show but I haven't found anyone taking about it.)

Our apache installation is configured to gzip responses. One of the headers was:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I turned off apache module and it now works!

Comment: Interesting finding and I think i can confirm it. Have you considered opening a bug on the firefox issue tracker?
A fix could be for firefox to support encoded rss-responses (should be preferred), or to not send the `accept-encoding: gzip`,... when requesting *.rss URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Type of the first is `application/xhtml+xml` while the Content Type of the second is just `text/xml`. As far as I can see all other feeds I have registered use Content Type `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: The actual response from http://www.alistapart.com/site/rss is "text/xml". When you "View Page Info" it shows application/xhtml+xml but I think that is just because Firefox is transforming the xml to display the interface. (I know its text/xml because I ran "wget http://www.alistapart.com/site/rss")